# Detected if a session is currently active and join instead of starting a new one

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I am facing a small issue with chromecast application session management on iOS sender app.

I want to be able to create an app session on the receiver and start playback.
Close the sender app while playback is happening on the sender.
open the app again and connect on the same device.
Join the same session and regain control of the receiver without pausing/stopping playback or restarting the whole session.

At the moment I am keeping track of the session ID for the device I'm connected on and execute

```
- (BOOL)joinApplication:(NSString *)applicationID sessionID:(NSString *)sessionID;
```

but I am unable to differentiate between a new session and an old one. 
Is there a way to know the current session id the Chromecast device is connected to?
That is to know if I should call join or launch application and start a new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only join the session if it is your previous one, then calling joinApplication and passing your old sessionId should either succeed (if it is still that very same session) or would fail (if it is a different session, whether from the same app or a different app). Isn't that what you want?

Comment: So, the solution would be to call join and if that fails the call launch?

I manage to achieve the desired effect, yet not properly tested yet, by calling [_manager launchWithAppID:kAppID relaunchIfNeeded:NO] and by creating a new media channel for that session. 

I will keep this question updated for anything relevant I find. 
Cheers!

Comment: As I said, if you want to join only if app is running and do not launch a new one, you need to use joinApplication and pass your session ID. If you want to join if it is running and launch if it is not running, then use launchApplication. launchApplication takes a parameter which forces a relaunch even if app is already running there; you probably don't want that.